# What's the meaning of "bottom third" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> If you sleep on your back: "Back sleepers need thinner pillows, so their head is not thrown too far forward," Bernard says. Also look for a pillow with extra loft in the **bottom third** of the pillow to cradle your neck.

Comment: bottom one-third (1/3rd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it means the third of the pillow that your neck will be on while you are sleeping. 
If you view your pillow by sitting directly in front of it, you will see that the "bottom third" of the pillow will be where your neck should be if you laid down.

Comment: fantastic ,thoroughly understood